# Django y autocomplete, ¿Como poder buscar por Nombre y Apellido?

Tags: django, autocompletar

Tengo el siguiente código que solo busca por el nombre de persona, no se me ocurre como poder buscar también por apellido, aqui les dejo el codigo que probe para buscar por apellido mas, pero no funciona no busca

## views.py

```
def Buscarpersona(request):
 if request.is_ajax():
    search = request.GET.get('start', '')
    #search2 = request.GET.get('start2', '')
    personas = personalProfile.objects.filter(nombre__A_Paterno__icontains=search)

    results = []
    for pl in personas and apellido:
        place_json ={
        'titulo':pl.titulo,
        'nombre':pl.nombre,
        'A_Paterno':pl.A_Paterno,
        'A_Materno':pl.A_Materno,
        }

        results.append(place_json)
    data = json.dumps(results)
else:
    data = 'fail'
mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

## Ajax

```
$(function() {
$("#id_user1").autocomplete({
  minLenght: 4,
  source: function(req, add){
    var search=$("#id_user1").val();
    $.ajax({
      url:"{% url 'user:Buscarpersona' %}",
      async:false,
      dataType:'json',
      type:'GET',
      data:{'start':search},
      success: function(data){

        var suggestions=[];
        $.each(data, function(index, objeto){
          suggestions.push(objeto.titulo+""+ objeto.nombre +" "+ objeto.A_Paterno +" "+ objeto.A_Materno);
        });
        add(suggestions);

      },
      error:function(err){
        alert("no existe el usuario");
      }
    });
  }

});
```

});

Creo q estoy haciendo mal uso del __icontains, corrijan me si me equivoco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que te puede interesar usar [objetos Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Debemos importar el módulo:

```
from django.db.models import Q
```

Y la consulta podría quedar así:

```
personas = personalProfile.objects.filter(Q(nombre__A_Paterno__icontains=search) | Q(apellido__icontains=search))
```

No sé si es exactamente lo que buscas, pero para muchas busquedas similares a la que porpones, yo estoy usando objetos Q. Espero que sea de ayuda.

Comment: muchas gracias evidentemente, si es lo que buscaba lo aplique en mi proyecto y me salio de maravilla ya busca por nombre y apellido, muchas gracias, por tu apoyo, enserio

Comment: Genial @Lun. De nada, recuerda que es conveniente marcar como válida una respuesta si es adecuada, sobre todo de cara a que los usuarios puedan ver que la pregunta tiene respuesta válida.

Answer (score 0):

Para alguien que tenga un problema similar ahí les dejo la parte que modifique para que funcione mi código.

## Libreria

from django.db.models import Q

## Parte del codigo views.py

```
def Buscarpersona(request):

 if request.is_ajax():
    search = request.GET.get('start', '')
    personas = personalProfile.objects.filter(Q(nombre__icontains=search)|Q(A_Paterno__icontains=search))
    results = []
    for pl in personas:
        place_json ={
        'titulo':pl.titulo,
        'nombre':pl.nombre,
        'A_Paterno':pl.A_Paterno,
        'A_Materno':pl.A_Materno,
        }

        results.append(place_json)
    data = json.dumps(results)
else:
    data = 'fail'
mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```